# Where Controls Declarations in a website project are put

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have website i cant access the controls in the code-behind

i drag controls and add them to ASPX file and when i try to access them i cant.

i tried opening the website using:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Visual Studio 2010

when i even double click on a button it creates its event in the code behind but i still cant access the control!

there is no designer.cs file since this is a web site any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, the markup *is* the designer for a page that lacks a designer file. You can observe this behavior in classic ASP pages that have been ported to .NET.

The compiler simply parses the page, looking for a tag that includes `runat="server"` and generates a server-side control for it. If there's no ID, one is generated for it. Further, if `AutoEventWireup="true"` is set at the page level, the events will be automatically connected to these controls, as if by magic. It's all just compiler voodoo, if you ask me, but rather convenient compiler voodoo.

But that's an educated guess, based on experience, and I'm sure someone with far more experience with ASP.NET internals can provide more riveting details. (Jon Skeet, et al.)

Comment: Nice now any idea why i cant access controls ?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific when you say "can't access the control." If you've gotten an event handler, the control name is in the event name. Further, the control itself is in the `sender` argument, and all you should have to do is cast it to its appropriate type.

Comment: Mind you, accessing *nested* controls can be tricky. You may want to do some research on the FindControl() method, which you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .aspx file specifies its codebehind file:
`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" CodeFile="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Content_YourPage" %>`

Comment: yes the aspx file specify its code-behind , when i even double click on a button it creates its event in the code behind but i still cant access the control!

Comment: Can you provide code of how the control you're trying to access is defined, and how you're trying to access it?

Comment: this is how its declared:  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
i try to access it like this : Button2.Text = "hi";

Comment: The name 'Button2' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It's not clear to me from the information provided why it's not working. Perhaps you could just paste your whole aspx and aspx.cs into your question. Maybe you are trying to access it outside a method or something?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a website then websites don't have designer.

But if you need the designer's then try to convert it to web application

Comment: how do i convert it to a web application ?

Comment: If you decide to convert it to web application here is a WalkThorugh http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx